# How to make Emacs autofill code for c files

Tags: emacs, macros

I'm completely new to Emacs and I'm looking for a way to make Emacs automatically write these lines of code for C files

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

I'm sorry for messing up these lines, but I think you've got the point.

Comment: C tag removed. Question is not about C in the context of SO.

Answer (score 1):

`Yasnippet` is perfect for re-usable snippets .

Have a look at the [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet)

Install using: `M-x package-install yasnippet`, or look on [project on github](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/master/README.mdown#installation).

Once installed, enable yasnippet-minor-mode with `M-x yas-minor-mode-on` (when your C file is open, the buffer's major mode is on `c-mode` and `yas-minor-mode` adds `yas` functionality.)

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>C-n</kbd> will open a buffer for a snippet.
Give it a name and copy your code into the body, result should look like:

```
# key: c
# name: c_include
# --
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> to close and save the buffer.

It will now appear with the name you gave it in the yasnippet menu when you call 
<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd>

Yasnippet has a lot more functionality. Read the doc.

Find C templates in [AndreaCrotti yasnippet snippets Github repository](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets)